# Why is node.js decoding the same string differently on different platforms?

Tags: node.js, windows, character-encoding

I currently have this string, `ƴǮǮȏϘЁЎϊդ࠷ࡔც`, which I have encoded w/ `encodeURIComponent` JS to become `%C6%B4%C7%AE%C7%AE%C8%8F%CF%98%D0%81%D0%8E%CF%8A%D5%A4%E0%A0%B7%E0%A1%94%E1%83%AA`.

When I try to decode it with decodeURIComponent in node.js on linux, I do get the original string back. However, when I try to decode it with node.js on Windows, I get this: `Æ´Ç®Ç®ÈÏ˜ÐÐŽÏŠÕ¤à ·à¡”áƒª`. Is there a reason why? It seems strange to me that the output is different across platforms.

Is this secretly the same thing in just a different encoding? How can I convert this Windows string back into the original form that I want it to be in?

Answer (score 1):

While it's possible you ran into a bug, Node.js *should* do the exact same thing on every platform.

What's more likely to me is one of these explanations:

1. The input data is different on each platform.
2. The tool you use to inspect the output is different on each platform, or the settings of these tools are different.

That's where you should be looking.

For what it's worth, the 'string' you posted is completely broken. At least in the way you posted it to stack overflow.

Most of javascript's string related tools expect UTF-8, and what you posted... well it could be many things but it doesn't look like human language. It looks like it 'used to be' valid text in some encoding, misintepreted by the wrong decoder and then copy-pasted to stackoverflow (which is UTF-8). It's mojibake